# SVG Text to be placed on a ring

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, svg

I want svg text to be placed on a ring. Is it possible to wrap it around? Any workarounds please? I have tried transform matrix, but I am not able to do with it.
[Example of ring image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXuob.jpg)

Comment: Please reas about [<textPath>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) You can use the ring inage inside an svg element. You will need to draw a path where you want to put your text. Next you use this path as a textPath inside the text element.

Comment: yes but with text path we can write text on path whereas I have to wrap text on a ring. So how can I create path which wraps around? Can you suggest, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a circle into a path. I used Inkscape for that. So, here is a basic example:

```html
<svg viewBox="-10 -10 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300">
  <defs>
  <path id="MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red"
        d="M 50,95 A 45,45 0 0 1 5,50 45,45 0 0 1 50,5 45,45 0 0 1 95,50 45,45 0 0 1 50,95 Z" />
  </defs>
  <text textLength="280">
    <textPath href="#MyPath">This is your text</textPath>
  </text>

</svg>
```

### Update

Maybe I misunderstood the question, so here is the new version. I'm not satisfied with the "skewing" if the text. I will update  this answer later.

```css
text {
 font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300">
  <defs>
  <path id="MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red"
        d="M 46.326016,82.135999 C 75.229867,67.395261 78.467889,35.580206 78.467889,35.580206" />
  </defs>
  <image width="100" height="100" href="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"/>
  <text textLength="50">
    <textPath class="text" href="#MyPath">This is your text</textPath>
  </text>

</svg>
```

Comment: you can use a circle directly in Firefox at least. Other browsers should catch up if they haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a Ring Bitmap to SVG Using `<image>`

Open the SVG file in a vector editor and create a path for the text

[image]

as **@enxaneta** comments:

> You can use the ring inage inside an svg element. You will need to
> draw a path where you want to put your text. Next you use this path as
> a textPath inside the text element.

*below is full code:*

```css
.container {
 width:60vw;
 height:60vh;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  id="svg4" viewBox="0 0 1181 1181">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pn89.jpg" id="image2" height="100%" width="100%"/>
  <path id="RingPath" d="M 286.49258,567.98094 C 326.93719,456.93269 377.70892,383.63001 427.86229,316.51801 534.88572,173.30617 639.45611,129.74376 639.45611,129.74376"  fill="none"  />
   <text font-size="60px" font-weight="bold" fill="#826B28">
    <textPath href="#RingPath">
      SVG Text to be placed
    </textPath>
  </text>
 </div> 
</svg>
```